# A simple rebus for you all!

Tags: rebus

[image: square root of negative one, 2³, uppercase Greek letter sigma, Greek letter pi]

A simple rebus puzzle for you all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It reads:

> i over eight sum pi

The explanation being:

> $\sqrt{-1}$ is *i* the [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit), fractions can be phrase as "*one thing* [over](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-x-over-y-in-mathematics) *another thing*", $2^3$ which equals $8$. Then $\Sigma$ indicates a mathematical sum, and $pi$ is the mathematical constant.

or read in plain English

> I overate some pie